# Can python access google chrome webSQL db

Tags: python, sqlite, google-chrome, web-sql

I have a local web client that uses webSQL to store its data client side. (Yes I know its been deprecated).

I also have a python script that generates a report and grabs its data from a mdb file right now using a driver.

I was wondering if it was possible to grab my data from google chrome's webSQL db through python.

I'm not sure how to call one of the db files in google chrome from a python script or if its even possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so my co-worker figured it out.

On windows you go to:

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```

There's a bunch of databases here for different websites that use sqlite.

And then the python script is as easy this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(<dbFile>)
cursor = conn.cursor()


print "\nHere's a listing of all the records in the table:\n"
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <TableName>"):
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right:
The interesting files in the Chrome UserData Folder (at least that is what it's called in Windows) are afaik either JSON files or SQLite database files. You can access the latter with the [sqlite3 module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) from the Python standard library. 
But the README there states:

```
Google Chrome settings and storage represent user-selected preferences and
information and MUST not be extracted, overwritten or modified except through
Google Chrome defined APIs.
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. We seem to be almost on the same page. I've tried using the sqlite3 module. The problem was I wasn't sure how to reference the files in google chrome. My co-worker actually just figured it out and I will be posting the answer shortly.

Comment: Ah! You were looking for the folder where the databases are. I misunderstood.